# Adding a command to latex-match-warning-keywords for tex-mode

Tags: syntax-highlighting, tex-mode

I want the commands `\largerpage` and `\addlines` to be displayed in red (`font-latex-match-warning-keywords`) but cannot figure out how to do this. I found several posts, but non of this seems to work.

This is what I tried:

```
;; \font-latex-warning-face
(setq font-latex-match-warning-keywords
    '(
        ("addlines" "") 
    )
)

 (font-lock-add-keywords nil '(("\\(addlines\\) \\(largerpage\\)" 
                                 0
                                 'font-latex-warning-face)))

(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode '(("addlines" 
                                            0
                                            'font-latex-warning-face)))
```

I am using GNU Emacs 24.5.1.

Comment: Have you tried the customize interface? (`M-x customize-group font-latex`).

Comment: I do not have a font-latex. Maybe I do not have auctex loaded. May .emace does not say anything about loading it. But I get syntax highliting for latex.

Comment: You are not using AUCTeX, so the solution is completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AddKeywords

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'latex-mode
                        '(("addlines" . font-lock-warning-face)
                          ("largerpage" . font-lock-warning-face)))
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `"\\\\addlines"` and `"\\\\largerpage"` to add the leading (single) slash (doubly escaped)?  I wanted to add `\cli{}` as a keywaord (command) and without slashes, any `cli` substring is coloured.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#Fontification-of-macros) suggests to use the customization group `font-lock-keywords`.  First visit a latex file to ensure AUCTeX is loaded, then do `M-x customize-group font-latex-keywords`, navigate to **Font Latex Match Warning Keywords**, *INS*ert your keywords, apply *Save for future sessions* and restart emacs.

If the customization group is unknown, do `M-: (require 'font-latex)` first. (It's not clear to me when/why it's necessary.)